# Nashorn is 3 times slower than Rhino, how to optimize?

Tags: performance, nashorn

I'm porting some code in my application from Rhino to Nashorn (mostly to keep up with modern fashion rather than lack of functionality in Rhino) and i'm getting really bad performance with Nashorn.

My app has set of LESS files to by compiled at run-time (content is dynamic and cannot be pre-compiled therefore). This is done once at startup and each time as changes are detected at run-time.

Rhino gives rather consistent performance of around 4-5 seconds (JS script is loaded with highest Rhino optimization).

Nashorn provides some absolutely weird results - around 15-17 seconds, but after 10th iteration and around 10 minutes of time performance becomes rather good - around 3 seconds. But because of initial slowness my app with Nashorn starts in general approximately 30 seconds longer than with Rhino (there are other LESS files compiled too).

So the question is:

**What can i do** to enforce Nashorn to perform highest optimization of the script right away, not after 10-20th iteration?

---

Below are the timings from log file

```
2015-11-11 09:29:16,419 compile(less, styles.less)  = 15179ms
--------------------------------------------------------------
   15.179       %  compile (styles.less)
--------------------------------------------------------------
   13.940   91.8%  less-rhino-ji.js lessFileToCss(styles.less)
    1.227    8.0%  YUICompressor minify(styles.less)

2015-11-11 09:30:12,900 compile(less, styles.less)  = 13274ms
--------------------------------------------------------------
   13.274       %  compile (styles.less)
--------------------------------------------------------------
   11.605   87.4%  less-rhino-ji.js lessFileToCss(styles.less)
    1.664   12.5%  YUICompressor minify(styles.less)

2015-11-11 09:30:43,705 compile(less, styles.less)  = 6906ms
--------------------------------------------------------------
    6.906       %  compile (styles.less)
--------------------------------------------------------------
    5.695   82.4%  less-rhino-ji.js lessFileToCss(styles.less)
    1.205   17.4%  YUICompressor minify(styles.less)

2015-11-11 09:31:09,194 compile(less, styles.less)  = 6041ms
--------------------------------------------------------------
    6.041       %  compile (styles.less)
--------------------------------------------------------------
    4.622   76.5%  less-rhino-ji.js lessFileToCss(styles.less)
    1.412   23.3%  YUICompressor minify(styles.less)

2015-11-11 09:31:49,558 compile(less, styles.less)  = 7619ms
--------------------------------------------------------------
    7.619       %  compile (styles.less)
--------------------------------------------------------------
    3.056   40.1%  less-rhino-ji.js lessFileToCss(styles.less)
    4.555   59.7%  YUICompressor minify(styles.less)

2015-11-11 09:36:25,586 compile(less, styles.less)  = 5226ms
--------------------------------------------------------------
    5.226       %  compile (styles.less)
--------------------------------------------------------------
    4.104   78.5%  less-rhino-ji.js lessFileToCss(styles.less)
    1.116   21.3%  YUICompressor minify(styles.less)

2015-11-11 09:36:40,745 compile(less, styles.less)  = 3839ms
--------------------------------------------------------------
    3.839       %  compile (styles.less)
--------------------------------------------------------------
    2.664   69.3%  less-rhino-ji.js lessFileToCss(styles.less)
    1.169   30.4%  YUICompressor minify(styles.less)

2015-11-11 09:37:02,876 compile(less, styles.less)  = 3074ms
--------------------------------------------------------------
    3.074       %  compile (styles.less)
--------------------------------------------------------------
    1.948   63.3%  less-rhino-ji.js lessFileToCss(styles.less)
    1.120   36.4%  YUICompressor minify(styles.less)

2015-11-11 09:37:29,140 compile(less, styles.less)  = 4773ms
--------------------------------------------------------------
    4.773       %  compile (styles.less)
--------------------------------------------------------------
    3.682   77.1%  less-rhino-ji.js lessFileToCss(styles.less)
    1.085   22.7%  YUICompressor minify(styles.less)

2015-11-11 09:37:51,768 compile(less, styles.less)  = 2761ms
--------------------------------------------------------------
    2.761       %  compile (styles.less)
--------------------------------------------------------------
    1.661   60.1%  less-rhino-ji.js lessFileToCss(styles.less)
    1.094   39.6%  YUICompressor minify(styles.less)

2015-11-11 09:38:19,053 compile(less, styles.less)  = 2743ms
--------------------------------------------------------------
    2.743       %  compile (styles.less)
--------------------------------------------------------------
    1.639   59.7%  less-rhino-ji.js lessFileToCss(styles.less)
    1.098   40.0%  YUICompressor minify(styles.less)
```

---

**Update**: 
By recommendation from Olipro I started process with following arguments:

```
java -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+PrintCompilation ...
```

The result is not absolutely clear - names of classes generated by Nashorn are like `jdk.nashorn.internal.scripts.Script$Recompilation$438$121292A$\^eval\_::L:3187$toCSS`, however just by method name I see that during the most lengthy compilation of CSS file (4.4 seconds) in that test run the method `toCSS()` was recompiled 5 times and it seems that 2 background threads were compiling different versions of same method in parallel (bit weird to me) - most probably this is indeed the root cause of bad performance.

Still - no hint how to improve startup performance :(

The lines from log ([1st column](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/architect-evans-pt1-2266278.html) = ms from jvm start):

```
11100 5677 jdk.nas...tion$438$121292A$\^eval\_::L:3187$toCSS (103 bytes)
11119 5682 jdk.nas...tion$446$150019A$\^eval\_::L:4147$toCSS (137 bytes)
11377 5677 jdk.nas...tion$438$121292A$\^eval\_::L:3187$toCSS (103 bytes)   made not entrant
11507 5677 jdk.nas...tion$438$121292A$\^eval\_::L:3187$toCSS (103 bytes)   made zombie
11932 5798 jdk.nas...tion$438$121292A$\^eval\_::L:3187$toCSS (103 bytes)
13381 5798 jdk.nas...tion$438$121292A$\^eval\_::L:3187$toCSS (103 bytes)   made not entrant
14272 5798 jdk.nas...tion$438$121292A$\^eval\_::L:3187$toCSS (103 bytes)   made zombie
14778 5682 jdk.nas...tion$446$150019A$\^eval\_::L:4147$toCSS (137 bytes)   made not entrant
14860 6049 jdk.nas...tion$438$121292A$\^eval\_::L:3187$toCSS (103 bytes)
14890 6056 jdk.nas...tion$446$150019A$\^eval\_::L:4147$toCSS (137 bytes)
15019 5682 jdk.nas...tion$446$150019A$\^eval\_::L:4147$toCSS (137 bytes)   made zombie
15223 6162 jdk.nas...tion$457$121460$\^eval\_::L:3187$toCSS$isEmpty (31 bytes)
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you're a victim of Java's JIT. Generally Java won't JIT code until it's done profiling on it and this sounds exactly like that situation.

Now, there *are* options you can pass when starting up the JRE to force it to native-compile everything immediately with `-Xcomp` or after less runs with `-XX:CompileThreshold` but both are generally not recommended.

If all the JVM instance does is act as nothing more than a glorified compiler, you could reasonably get away with trying `-Xcomp` but if your program is expected to be long lived, let it be. In any case though, I certainly recommend passing `-server`

Comment: I tried using `-Xcomp` - the final result is signiiiificantly worse performance. Overall startup time increased from 1:40 mins to 15:30. So, not sure what happens in JVM behind the scenes, but `-Xcomp` does not optimize anything in my case.

Comment: Right, `-Xcomp` results in the JVM compiling *everything* to native machine code and thus why it's not recommended. I would suggest reviewing the options here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html#BABDDFII and enable logging of compilation activity so you can get some insight as to how Java is making the process progressively faster.